I have been trying to run the testscript.py file to check my DeepLabCut installation and I encounter this error
(DEEPLABCUT) C:\Users\saleh\DeepLabCut\examples>python testscript.py
Loading DLC 3.0.0rc1...
Imported DLC!
On Windows/OSX tensorpack is not tested by default.
CREATING PROJECT
Project "C:\Users\saleh\DeepLabCut\examples\TEST-Alex-2024-06-19" already exists!
EXTRACTING FRAMES
Config file read successfully.
Extracting frames based on kmeans ...
Kmeans-quantization based extracting of frames from 0.0  seconds to 8.53  seconds.
Extracting and downsampling... 256  frames from the video.
256it [00:01, 234.06it/s]
Kmeans clustering ... (this might take a while)
Frames were successfully extracted, for the videos listed in the config.yaml file.

You can now label the frames using the function 'label_frames' (Note, you should label frames extracted from diverse videos (and many videos; we do not recommend training on single videos!)).
CREATING-SOME LABELS FOR THE FRAMES
C:\Users\saleh\DeepLabCut\examples\testscript.py:118: FutureWarning: Starting with pandas version 3.0 all arguments of to_hdf except for the argument 'path_or_buf' will be keyword-only.
  dataFrame.to_hdf(
Plot labels...
Creating images with labels by Alex.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\saleh\DeepLabCut\examples\testscript.py", line 132, in <module>
    deeplabcut.check_labels(path_config_file)
  File "C:\Users\saleh\anaconda3\envs\DEEPLABCUT\lib\site-packages\deeplabcut\generate_training_dataset\trainingsetmanipulation.py", line 364, in check_labels
    visualization.make_labeled_images_from_dataframe(
  File "C:\Users\saleh\anaconda3\envs\DEEPLABCUT\lib\site-packages\deeplabcut\utils\visualization.py", line 321, in make_labeled_images_from_dataframe
    h, w = ic[0].shape[:2]
  File "C:\Users\saleh\anaconda3\envs\DEEPLABCUT\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\collection.py", line 325, in __getitem__
    self.data[idx] = self.load_func(self.files[n], **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\saleh\anaconda3\envs\DEEPLABCUT\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\_plugins\imageio_plugin.py", line 11, in imread
    out = np.asarray(imageio_imread(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\saleh\anaconda3\envs\DEEPLABCUT\lib\site-packages\imageio\v3.py", line 53, in imread
    with imopen(uri, "r", **plugin_kwargs) as img_file:
  File "C:\Users\saleh\anaconda3\envs\DEEPLABCUT\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\imopen.py", line 281, in imopen
    raise err_type(err_msg)
OSError: Could not find a backend to open `C:\Users\saleh\DeepLabCut\examples\TEST-Alex-2024-06-19\labeled-data\reachingvideo1\CollectedData_Alex.csv`` with iomode `r`.

(DEEPLABCUT) C:\Users\saleh\DeepLabCut\examples>

Can anyone please help me identify what is causing this?

describe it in question's body, not in title.

what is DeepLabCut ? How we have to test it without code? You could at least add link to source code (and documentation).

it seems it use imread() (which is for reading images) to open file csv (which is NOT image format)

This is the link to the main code repository: https://github.com/DeepLabCut/DeepLabCut

better put it in question - so every people may see it. And when more people may see all details then more people can help you. So always put all details in question.
